# How to update only specific columns in database from Django admin panel?

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I have a table named "temp". It has 2 columns "a" and "b". Both columns have 50 rows of data. I added another column "c" and I need that column to get filled with 50 rows of data. I have a excel file that contains the data for column "c".

How can I do this? How can I just update the values of column "c"? I know I can just update a file using the Django admin panel but it will update all the columns. I don't want that.

Is there a way to use default Django import export functionality in the admin page and make only a certain column get updated? Also I am using mysql for database.

I am new to Django.

Comment: I don't know about django panel, but could you import your excel to a totally different table, and then use that to update your existing table?

Comment: I just want a single column to get updated with the values containing in a excel or csv file

Comment: Yes, you said that in the question. Did you not understand something in my comment?